# Java - How to change the version of the app

Tags: java, ant, javafx-2

I am new to Java standalone app development.

I implemented a Java standalone app using JavaFX, created the executable using Apache ant and installed it in my windows machine.

The version number of the app as 1.0 in the control panel. Now I want to change that version number. How do I do it?

We can find the build.xml [here](http://paste.org/68523)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this hint:

```
<fx:application id="abs-client" name="${application.title}" version="2.0"
                       mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
```

here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm